# Lodash remove object by inner object elements condition

Tags: node.js, typescript, lodash, underscore.js

I need to remove some objects.

My main object is:

```
[
    {
        objectName: {...somefields}
        list: [
            {
                pr: {id: 'someid1',
                l: [
                       {
                          ...someFields,
                          count: 0
                       },
                       {
                          ...someFields,
                          count: 33
                       },
                ]
            },
            {. <--- need to remove this object
                pr: {id: 'someid2',
                l: [
                       {
                          ...someFields,
                          count: 0
                       },
                       {
                          ...someFields,
                          count: 0
                       },
                       {
                          ...someFields,
                          count: 0
                       }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        objectName: {...somefields}
        list: [
            { <--- and this one
                pr: {id: 'someid3',
                l: [
                       {
                          ...someFields,
                          count: 0
                       },
                       {
                          ...someFields,
                          count: 0
                       },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to remove objects where all of count fields is 0.

In this array of objects is 'someid2' and 'someid3'.

But length of **list** array, **l** array and objects in **main object** can be different.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const somefields = {
    name: "name",
    desc: "description"
};

let mainObject = [
    {
        objectName: { ...somefields },
        list: [
            {
                pr: {
                    id: "someid1",
                    l: [
                        {
                            ...somefields,
                            count: 0
                        },
                        {
                            ...somefields,
                            count: 33
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                pr: {
                    id: "someid2",
                    l: [
                        {
                            ...somefields,
                            count: 0
                        },
                        {
                            ...somefields,
                            count: 0
                        },
                        {
                            ...somefields,
                            count: 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        objectName: { ...somefields },
        list: [
            {
                pr: {
                    id: "someid3",
                    l: [
                        {
                            ...somefields,
                            count: 0
                        },
                        {
                            ...somefields,
                            count: 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];

const result = mainObject.map(o => {
    o.list = o.list.filter(item => {
        return !_.every(item.pr.l, el => el.count === 0);
    });
    return o;
});



console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```